# Entity Framework, Stored Procedures and everything

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

So, I promised to see if I could help a friend with a small asp MVC application. I've started to regret it though since I haven't touched Entity Framework for many years.
We have a MSSQL database where users can post and list their own data (only). We don't want to have individual DB users, users logon using OAuth with external providers, which is working good.
Now we need to fix the CRUS and match the useridentity with his own posts. From our discussions there's three paths ahead.

1. Handling all the CRUD in webapp-code, a lot of examples and seem to work nice. My friend is kind of DB-centric though and an open database where someone suddenly could list all data using Crystal or Excel scares him.
2. Handling it in views, this is kind of a small webapp for now but I guess that could result in slow JOINS if there are a lot of posts in the end.
3. Handling all the CRUD with Stored Procedures, old style

I haven't used Entity Framework since it was brand new so I'm not aware of it's features today. Any advice or good resources on why to choose one over the other are welcome
Best Regards!

Comment: there are examples and tutorials at http://www.asp.net/mvc which show CRUD and EF.

Comment: Yes, I stepped through them it's a good site for resources

Comment: This tutorial might help http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, you propose "code first" and handling it all in the webapp? (need to wrestle my friend then, but I'm heavier ;)

Comment: MVC apps with EF Code First works great, i agree with Tushar

Comment: Most examples I find is "Code first" and I'm more a coder than a DBA, my friend will of course claim that users might bypass all restriction and logic using Crystal, Excel or whatever tool when they connect to the DB

Comment: EF Code First Existing Database may work well.